# Django 1.4 - query iteration using fields stored in a dictionary

Tags: django, python-2.7, dictionary, django-models, django-1.4

I had a huge registration table with 112 fields. For a particular search I want to compare 17 fields & assign colors to variable say 'clrSelected'. 
My code is :

```
reg = Regisration.objects.filter('some condition').order_by("name") 
for r in reg:
  if r.name=='abc': clrSelected='#fff'
  if r.type=='1': clrSelected='#000'
  if r.appl=='10': clrSelected='#c1ff51'
  if r.code=='': clrSelected='#60c5f7'
  if r.qlty=='first': clrSelected='#f99334'
  ...
  ...
```

there will be only one **if** condition, which need to be colored. Which means the field(from the dictionary) to be compared will change based on the user selection.
I want to access the field name from a dictionary like this

```
flds = {'1':'name', '2':'type', '3':'appl', '4':'code', '5':'qlty',...}
```

And use it something like this

```
if r.flds['1']=='abc': clrSelected='#fff'
```

How could i use the fields as above. I am using django 1.4 & python 2.7

Comment: is your question: 'how do I dynamically access fields from variable names?'? Is there any reason you are using a dictionary as the structure to store the field names rather than a list?

Comment: yup..i want to dynamically access a field from dictionary. the field to access depends on user selection.

Comment: As the answer says, use `getattr` to dynamically access the field. You do not need a dictionary. A list here would work equally well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to answer the question, you could use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
if getattr(r, flds['1']) == 'abc': clrSelected = '#fff'
```

---

However, I am pretty sure that you could go with a different kind of implementation in this case which doesn't require using a `dict` like this.

I would suggest using a three tuple list: (fieldName, value, color)

```
some_list  = [('name', 'abc', '#fff'), ('type', '1', '#000'), ...]
```

And, then use this list to determine the color:

```
for fieldName, value, color in some_list:
    if getattr(r, fieldName) == value:
        clrSelected = color
```

Looking at your implementation, it seems the color will be based on the last `if` condition which matches. If that is the case, you could create `some_list` in reverse order and `break` on the first matching condition.

Comment: thnk u..let me try using getattr. Also there will be only one **if** condition in my code, based on the field which is need to be colored(user selection), i wil edit the question.